# Rotating a sphere in threejs not working if using a loop

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to have a sphere rotated a certain number of times when a button is clicked (the number of times is selected by the user). Since the number of rotations is open ended, I figured it would be easiest to have it done in a `for` loop:

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function () {
    var multiple = 4; //Change this value to rotate at different angles
    var rotationVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
    var angle = ((360 / multiple) * Math.PI) / 180;
    for (var i = 0; i < multiple; i++) {
        sphere.rotateOnAxis(rotationVector, angle);
        alert(i);
    }
});
```

The `alert` is just a placeholder for now, but I do want other things done after each rotation. The problem here is that the rotation is never done. There's no errors and it hits that line of code, but the object never rotates. If I take the `sphere.rotateOnAxis` out of the for loop, then it works fine (at least it rotates once per click). I've tried various methods of re-rendering the scene, but that never does anything.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/weatL3nc/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice what you're doing here:

```
var angle = ((360 / multiple) * Math.PI) / 180;
```

You're getting an angle by dividing 360 degrees (or 2 *π* radians) into *n* slices. Then here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < multiple; i++) {
    sphere.rotateOnAxis(rotationVector, angle);
}
```

You're rotating *n* times by that angle. That means that no matter what `multiple` was, at the end of the for loop, you'll have rotated precisely 360 degrees. In other words, it *is* working, you just won't ever notice it because the next time it draws the screen, the sphere will be right back where it was before.

As an alternative you can try to using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) to allow the screen to redraw between frames, like this:

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function () {
    var multiple = 2; //Change this value to rotate at different angles
    var rotationVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
    var angle = ((360 / multiple) * Math.PI) / 180;
    var frame = 0;
    var ival = setInterval(function() {
        sphere.rotateOnAxis(rotationVector, angle);
        frame++;
        alert('Frame ' + frame + ' of ' + multiple);
        if (multiple == frame)
            clearInterval(ival);
    }, 1);
});
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/weatL3nc/4/)

Comment: But if it's alerting me after each rotation (or really doing anything after each rotation), shouldn't I see it at least rotated partially?

Comment: @Braffin It doesn't redraw the screen until after the loop completes.

Comment: I suggest you add at least the instructions to solve the problem (moving the `angle = ..` inside the loop) to make your answer complete.

Comment: @rcdmk It's not entirely clear from the question if OP is really attempting to animate the sphere or do something else (not sure what moving `angle =` would accomplish). The sphere *is* rotating as expected, OP just can't see it.

Comment: @rcdmk The value of `angle` is never going to change within the loop. If I put that calculation inside the loop, then it would just be calculating the same number over and over.

@p.s.w.g What I want to do, is rotate the sphere 1 rotation (whatever that angle is), then capture the canvas at that moment as a screenshot. Basically take screenshot, rotate 180*, take screenshot. But if it's not re-rendering until after the loop, then that is obviously a problem.

Comment: @Braffin So is this basically manual process? i.e. wait for the alert, screenshot, then click okay, repeated *n* times. If so, why not just remove the for loop and click the 'click me' button *n* times?

Comment: Sorry, no, not manual. I put the alert in there thinking it would pause the loop after a single rotation. The actual screenshot process is done all in code with `renderer.domElement.toDataURL()`.

Comment: @Braffin have you tested the code as is with `toDataURL()`? I'm not sure, but I think invoking that might generate the correct image data even if the screen hasn't redrawn yet.

Comment: Yup, I've tested if with `toDataURL()`, but ti doesn't get the correct image data. It just takes 2 screenshots with the sphere in the same position. I updated the jsFiddle example to include the screenshot code: http://jsfiddle.net/weatL3nc/3/.

Comment: Well, thanks to a few comments here I got it working. I simply had to add the line `renderer.render(scene,camera);`. I had tried calling my render function (`render()`) after each rotation, but that never did anything. Apparently just the single line works.

Answer (score 1):

To wait for the render to complete you can implement a `setTimeout()` insted of a `for` loop with an interval high enough to wait for the render:

```
var iteration = 0;
var multiple = 4;
var interval = 100; // ms
var angle = ((360 / multiple) * Math.PI) / 180;

function rotateAndSave() {
    iteration++;
    sphere.rotateOnAxis(rotationVector, angle);
    //alert(iteration);
    if (iteration < maxIterations) setTimeout(rotateAndSave, interval);
}
```

Then call this function on your click:

```
rotateAndSave();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/weatL3nc/6/

Comment: Oh, I see. The rotation method rotates incrementally, offseting the angle with the current one. It makes sense. I'll fix my example code.